# I am getting error "X... no configure: error: X development" while installing gtk+-3.12.2

Tags: linux, unix

I am getting the error below while running the `./configure` script when installing the gtk+-3.12.2 package.

I have already installed libX11-1.6.2 package.

**checking for gdk-pixbuf-csource... $HOME/pratik/local/bin/gdk-

   pixbuf-csource checking for X... no configure: error: X development 
   libraries not found**

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Where did you download from, how did you install, where did you install? Your question lacks a lot of details; as it stands, tempted to nominate for closing as "too broad".

Comment: i have downloaded package libX11-1.6.2 from this site [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libx11/2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libx11/2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2) and gtk+-3.12.2 package [http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html                ](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/x/gtk3.html) and i am running this command `./configure --prefix=$HOME/pratik/local
`

Comment: On Ubuntu, you need to install the `libX11-dev` package to get the headers etc. It's still not clear what you have done to install it but this is a common misunderstanding.

Comment: package **libX11-1.6.2** already install . and what is difference between **libX11-1.6.2** and **libX11-dev**
i install the package in simple way . Just download the package and extract this package using `tar -xvf filename` and then run this command `./configure --prefix=$HOME/pratik/local`

Comment: The difference is that `apt-get install libX11` will install the wrong package, and `apt-get install libX11-dev` will install the one you need. They contain different files; the base package is the runtime library, and the development package contains the C header files etc. Again, this is a common question; google for a bit.